# two-way communication Socket.IO in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket, socket.io

Good morning, I am doing a bidirectional communication using the python socket.io library, with the link code I manage to obtain the data sent from the client to the server, but I have not given to send data from the server to the client, I have looked for information in google but I have not had results

Programa
https://gist.github.com/sidwarkd/282fa9ee820663f1da3cc731e69434e4

Comment: Its on the intro page of Python socket io? https://python-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html

Comment: On the page is not an example of sending server to client

Comment: There is though... Maybe this sentence will help you: "This is achieved simply by returning the desired values from the handler function". I really don't know how to explain it better than the docs, I'm sorry.